# MeshLab: processing multiple files in meshlabserver

Tags: cmd, command, mesh

I'm new to using meshlabserver and meshlab in general.
I created the .mlx file and tries to run a command in meshlabserver for one file and it worked. I would like to know how do I write a command for hundreds of files?

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've just created a batch file with necessary loops and calls the .mlx file that will run the meshlabserver command. However one should know that the resulting files will be saved in the same directory where meshlabserver.exe is.